# HTML Table - show div content from one cell in a column over another cell div in another column

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am trying to show a div in a table cell over a div in another cell.

The HTML looks like:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="b"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
</tr>
    <tr>
        <td><div class="c"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
</tr>
```

And style:

```
td {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 50px;
    height: 30px;
}
.b {
    width: 100px;
    height: 80px;
    background: #f90;
    border: 1px solid #f60;
    margin-bottom: -50px;
    z-index:3;
}
.c {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #390;
    border: 1px solid #f60;
    z-index:-3;
}
```

I tried several ways but in vain. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Is this what are you looking for? http://jsbin.com/hefuj/1/edit Please include some image to show how you want the output

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if i get it right but i end in this solution:

```
td {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 50px;
    height: 30px;
}
.b {
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    background: #f90;
    border: 1px solid #f60;
   top:47px;
    z-index:3;
    position:absolute;
}
.c {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #390;
    border: 1px solid #f60;
    z-index:-3;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yg35n/3/)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
.b {
width: 100%;
height: 240%;
background: #f90;
border: 1px solid #f60;
z-index: 99;
position: relative;
margin-top: 25px;
    }

.c {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: #390;
border: 1px solid #f60;
position: relative;
}
```

Adjust the width & height of first div as per your needs